# Print array elements in a label

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

Every time I click on the button, I get the result as "5". I would like to iterate through an array and display all the elements in a `resultLabel`.

```
protected void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] myArray = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    {
        resultLabel.Text = String.Join(" ", myArray[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is iterating over each element of the list, but on each iteration you are are forming a string comprising only that element.

Suggest what you need is:

```
resultLabel.Text += " " + myArray[i].ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a loop, just [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) is enough and it will *Concatenates the members of a collection*:

```
resultLabel.Text = String.Join(" ", myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the contents of the array in the label, why do you need to iterate? Something like this should work

```
protected void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] myArray = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    resultLabel.Text = String.Join(" ",myArray);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.Join` is the best option to perform it. Alternatively another option is `Aggregate`.

```
resultLabel.Text = myArray.Aggregate("", (a, b) => a + " " + b).Trim();
```

Comment: What does this one do? Does this have an option to define a range to select from inside an array?